# API doesn't always return all photos in an album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

When I ask for photos in certain albums I receive only part of the images, while when I use facebook.com I can see them all.

For example: `/3738185490005/photos?fields=id` returns 4 images:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "3805142683893", 
      "created_time": "2012-06-05T20:11:54+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "3744666692031", 
      "created_time": "2012-05-25T18:40:26+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "3738416375777", 
      "created_time": "2012-05-24T14:41:45+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "3738185530006", 
      "created_time": "2012-05-24T13:41:37+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I look at Facebook itself I see 9 images. Also when I look at the album call: `/3738185490005` I see `"count": 9`. All images in this album are shared with Friends. I have seen this with multiple kinds of albums, but it happens most (as far as I can see) with Mobile Uploads or Instagram albums.

What can cause this?

Comment: see my answer..may be helped.....if you have any query i will helped...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 1):

```
try /3738185490005/photos?fields=id&limit=100
```

Answer (score 1):

[Even with a valid access_token with right set of permissions, FacebookClient does not get ALL of the photos for given album id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827638/even-with-a-valid-access-token-with-right-set-of-permissions-facebookclient-doe/22873872#22873872)

To ADD "user_checkins" to the scope collection to get all of the photos that are in a given album. Please follow the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I made an app, and nothing like that happened.. For the album that is not hidden to the user, all pics of that album are shown.

To be in the safe side, try using the access token along with the api call.

Comment: For most albums there is no problem, but there are some exceptions. As I do get the same results with the Graph API Explorer (with full rights), I fear it's in all apps.